# Computing Solid Geometry from Surfaces - CAD

Tags: general-topology, solid-geometry

I'm an engineer and I recently took a course at my local university about CAD curves and surfaces. I understand how NURBS surfaces work and how to generate the complex surfaces that models consist of.

What I don't understand, however, is how they determine that the surfaces are properly joined together to make a solid. I've searched in textbooks and in journals and all I've been able to come up with is something about the Euler characteristic.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to determine whether or not the surfaces form a 2-manifold. In CAD terms, this means that each edge is shared by exactly two faces. This is necessary, but is not enough, by itself, because the faces of a 2-manifold might be self-intersecting, which would mean that (arguably) they do not define a valid solid. Imagine a cube-like shape, with six faces, each of which is a NURBS surface. This is certainly a 2-manifold, and it defines a solid body. Now take the top face and deform it's middle portion downwards. Keep pulling downwards until the top face passes through the bottom face. You still have a 2-manifold, but it no longer defines a solid body.

The Euler characteristic is (originally) a property of polyhedra (solid bodies wih planar faces). It can be extended to curved surfaces, but it's not much value in telling you whether or not you have a solid body. Again, think about the cube-like model described above. As you deform its surfaces, its ability to represent a valid solid body will change, but its Euler characteristic will not.

Comment: I'm figuring "shared" basically means that the Hausdorff distance between the boundaries of the faces would be below some tolerance, like 1e-8? I'm figuring B-rep faces will have different degree curves on the boundary, so I would need to determine how close these curves are to being considered the same.

Comment: In addition to face-face and self-intersections, are there any other checks I would need to do in order to determine the "closedness" of the solid faces? I guess I'm looking for something like necessary and sufficient conditions.

Comment: Yes, "sharing" means that the two face are *logically" connected to the same edge, in the modeler's topological data structures. But then there is the geometric issue that you mention, too. In many situations, there will be two geometric reps of the edge, one on each face, and these two geometric reps must be within some tolerance of each other (measured as Haudorff distance), or else you have an inconsistency. In modern modelers, the tolerance value is typically stored with each edge; it's not a global constant.

Comment: Regarding necessary and sufficient conditions ... Your modeler will look at the stored data, and it will decide whether it can interpret this as a solid body. Different modelers use different criteria. In most modelers, there will a validity checking function that allows you find out whether it regards a given data set as a valid solid body.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I work closely with the geometry kernels and I'm familiar with their functions, but I'm wondering about the mathematics. Are there necessary and sufficient conditions or is there a book/journal article/etc that you know of that I can read to learn more about this?

Comment: Good places to start are the books on solid modeling by Chris Hoffmann and Martti Mantyla. But in some ways the mathematics is irrelevant -- if your modeling kernel thinks that a model is invalid, then it will (probably) refuse to use it, regardless of the mathematics.